# update state from context return error 'setState is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

**Description**

I am creating a dark/light mode feature using context in useContext in React.JS, but I am encountering a problem. I am new to using useContext in react.js, so I am asking for help to find the problem.

**Problem**

When i set theme, it returns error.

[image]

**Code**

ModeProvider.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

export const ModeContext = React.createContext([])

const ModeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true)
  return (
    <ModeContext.Provider value={[darkMode, setDarkMode]}>
      {children}
    </ModeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ModeProvider
```

ModeButton.js (as component)

```
import React from "react"
import DayIcon from "images/daymode.svg"
import NightIcon from "images/nightmode.svg"
import { ImgButton } from "./ModeButton.styles"

const ModeButton = ({ darkMode, setDarkMode }) => (
  <ImgButton
    src={darkMode ? NightIcon : DayIcon}
    alt="mode"
    onClick={() => setDarkMode(prevState => !prevState)}
  />
)

export default ModeButton
```

Header.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import useConfigQuery from '../../hooks/useConfigQuery'
import { Wrapper, Logo } from './Header.styles'
import Menu from 'components/Menu'
import Hamburger from 'components/Hamburger'
import MobileMenu from 'components/MobileMenu'
import ModeButton from "components/ModeButton"
import { ModeContext } from '../../context/ModeProvider'

const Header = ({ siteTitle = "" }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useContext(ModeContext);
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const siteConfig = useConfigQuery()

  return (
    <Wrapper>
        <Hamburger menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/>
        <MobileMenu menuOpen={menuOpen} items={siteConfig.menu}/>
        <Menu items={siteConfig.menu}/>
        <Link to="/">
            <Logo src={siteConfig.logo.publicURL} alt={siteTitle}/>
        </Link>
        <ModeButton darkMode={darkMode} setDarkMode={setDarkMode} />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Layout.js

```
import Header from 'components/Header'
import { ModeContext } from 'context/ModeProvider'

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [darkMode] = useContext(ModeContext);
  const data = useMetaDataQuery();

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
        <GlobalStyles/>
        <Header siteTitle={data.title}/>
        {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

**Question**

How to fix the update state code so the error can be resolved ?
Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: None of this code shows where you insert `ModeProvider` into the element hierarchy ... if that's missing then you'll just be getting the default `ModeContext`, which is an empty array without a value for `setDarkMode`.

Comment: i don't get it sir, can you spot the problem ?

Comment: Have elaborated in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be providing a `ModeContext.Provider` – you don't include it in the component hierarchy (or, if you do you're not showing that bit of the code).

It will need to be in another component that *encloses* all components where you're calling `useContext(ModeContext)`, e.g.

```js
import Header from 'components/Header'
import ModeProvider, { ModeContext } from 'context/ModeProvider'

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
    <ModeProvider>
        <InnerLayout>{children}</InnerLayout>
    </ModeProvider>
);

const InnerLayout = ({ children }) => {   
  const [darkMode] = useContext(ModeContext);
  const data = useMetaDataQuery();

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
        <GlobalStyles/>
        <Header siteTitle={data.title}/>
        {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```